# Cdk to add Http headers in lambda integration request

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-http-api

I have to add few http headers mapped to the context values comes from the lambda authorizer as shown below

```
"context": {
    "company_id": "xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxx",
    "Owner":"xxxxx",
  }
```

and the headers will be sent to the minimal api.

Can anyone help me on the cdk code(.ts) that send the custom headers to the .net api.

Comment: have you been able to fix it? I have the exact same problem. I need to inject some headers with values coming in the JWT payload.

Comment: @rmpt Yes, I have taken the context values from the httpcontext in my API

Comment: was it custom claims or other values? I can access "normal" values through `$context.authorizer.claims.whatever`, but I want to access some custom claims, specifically `custom:api_key`, but cdk complains about the `:`. I'm using HttpApi with HttpAlbIntegration to do this (with parameterMapping).

Comment: try the below code to get context from the aws authorizer and the below code is in c#

`if (httpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Count() > 0)
{ foreach (var header in httpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(x => x)) { switch (header.Type.ToLower()) { case "ownertype":ownerType = header.Value; break;  }  } }`